# JpaRespository deleteBy... does not work in certain condition

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make a simple time-based strategy game... 
This is the database connection: kingdom(OneToMany) -> progression, building, resource, troop
[image: mySQL connection kingdom(OneToMany) -> progression, building, resource, troop]

If I do this:

```
public void updateProgression(Kingdom kingdom) throws TroopNotFoundException, BuildingNotFoundException {
        List<ProgressionModel> progressions = kingdom.getKingdomsProgresses();
        for (ProgressionModel p : progressions) {
            System.out.println(p.getId());
            System.out.println(p.getType());
            System.out.println(p.getGameObjectId());
            System.out.println(p.getProgressKingdom().getId());
            if (timeService.timeIsUp(p)) {
                progress(p, kingdom);
            }
        }
   }
```

```
    private void progress(ProgressionModel progressionModel, Kingdom kingdom) throws TroopNotFoundException,
            BuildingNotFoundException {
        if (progressionModel.getGameObjectId() == null) {
            if (progressionModel.getType().equals("TROOP")) {
                troopService.createTroop(kingdom);
                progressionModelRepository.deleteById(progressionModel.getId());
                return;
            }
            buildingService.createBuilding(progressionModel, kingdom);
            System.out.println(progressionModel.getId());
            progressionModelRepository.deleteById(progressionModel.getId());
            return;
```

Hibernate queries in the console:

```
Hibernate: select kingdomspr0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_5_3_0_, kingdomspr0_.id as id1_3_0_, kingdomspr0_.id as id1_3_1_, kingdomspr0_.game_object_id as game_obj2_3_1_, kingdomspr0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_5_3_1_, kingdomspr0_.time_to_progress as time_to_3_3_1_, kingdomspr0_.type as type4_3_1_ from progression kingdomspr0_ where kingdomspr0_.kingdom_id=?
1
FARM
null
1
Hibernate: select kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_7_4_0_, kingdomsre0_.id as id2_4_0_, kingdomsre0_.id as id2_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.amount as amount3_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.resource_per_minute as resource4_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_7_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.type as type5_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.updated_at as updated_6_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.dtype as dtype1_4_1_ from resources kingdomsre0_ where kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id=?
Hibernate: update resources set amount=?, resource_per_minute=?, kingdom_id=?, type=?, updated_at=? where id=?
Hibernate: insert into buildings (hp, kingdom_id, level, type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Farm')
1
```

It won't delete the progression...

But if I call a JpaRepository built in query to get all the progressions belonging to the kingdom in the updateProgression method:

```
List<ProgressionModel> progressions = progressionModelRepository.findAllByProgressKingdom(kingdom);
```

Then hibernate deletes the progression from the progression table (which I want to achieve in the first scenario):

```
Hibernate: select progressio0_.id as id1_3_, progressio0_.game_object_id as game_obj2_3_, progressio0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_5_3_, progressio0_.time_to_progress as time_to_3_3_, progressio0_.type as type4_3_ from progression progressio0_ where progressio0_.kingdom_id=?
1
FARM
null
1
Hibernate: select kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_7_4_0_, kingdomsre0_.id as id2_4_0_, kingdomsre0_.id as id2_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.amount as amount3_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.resource_per_minute as resource4_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id as kingdom_7_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.type as type5_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.updated_at as updated_6_4_1_, kingdomsre0_.dtype as dtype1_4_1_ from resources kingdomsre0_ where kingdomsre0_.kingdom_id=?
Hibernate: update resources set amount=?, resource_per_minute=?, kingdom_id=?, type=?, updated_at=? where id=?
Hibernate: insert into buildings (hp, kingdom_id, level, type) values (?, ?, ?, 'Farm')
1
Hibernate: delete from progression where id=?
```

I can't get my head around this problem. Of course the code works if I use the repository call to get the progressions belonging to the kingdom but I really don't understand why a deleteById is not doing anything even though I pass a valid Id to it. Thanks for the help! I hope the composition is good enough to understand. This is my first question on StackOverflow btw so hit me with constructive criticism please.

Comment: isnt there any exception thrown? have you tried just delete(progressionModel)?

Comment: With all due respect sir please read my question before you answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are stumbling over the write-behind behavior of JPA.

When you delete an entity or update it in any way JPA doesn't write the changes to the database right away. 
The actual writing happens only at a flush event, or if it is necessary for some other reason like obtaining an id for a newly created entity.

Flush events get triggered in the following situations:

1. The transaction ends.
2. If you query the database. 
   This is to ensure that you see the updated data with your query.
   It also can be configured not to trigger a flush if you want to.
3. If you explicitly call flush on the `EntityManager`. If you are using Spring Data JPA this can be done by using a [`JpaRepository` and calling `flush()` on it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--).